# Enter Integers into an Array and terminating input before reaching limit

Tags: java

I'm doing a practice question in my textbook to add integers (negative and positive) into an array. I want the user to be able to terminate entering numbers into the array before it reaches the end [50].

This is what I've come up with:

The user enters the numbers which is stored in a string. If keepLooping is true and index < size of the array; it will parse token by token the string and place the number into the int array.

There must be an easier way to do this and I can't get my code working, any help would be much appreciated:

```
// Create Objects to use in program
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arrayOfNumbers = new int[50];


    // Prompt for input
    System.out.println("Enter upto 50 integers separated by a space.");
    System.out.println("Type x to signal no more integers to enter.");

    int index = 0;
    boolean keepLooping = true;

    while (index < arrayOfNumbers.length && keepLooping) {
        String numToAdd = keyboard.nextLine();

        if ( numToAdd.equals("x") || numToAdd.equals("X") ) {
            keepLooping = false;
        }

        if ( !numToAdd.equals("x") || !numToAdd.equals("X") ) {
            arrayOfNumbers[index] = Integer.parseInt(numToAdd); 
        }
    }

    // DEBUG, Print Array
    for (int k=0; k < arrayOfNumbers.length; k++) {
        System.out.println(arrayOfNumbers[k]);
    }
```

Comment: `index` never changes.

Comment: And what is the **error**?

Comment: increment the index++ with in the while loop

Comment: `if ( !numToAdd.equals("x") || !numToAdd.equals("X") )`

Also, this condition will always be true

Answer (score 2):

If you debugged your program step-by-step (e.g. Stepping with <kbd>F6</kbd> in Eclipse), you would have noticed that `index`'s value does not change. Quickest fix would be:

```
while (index < arrayOfNumbers.length && keepLooping) {
    String numToAdd = keyboard.nextLine();

    if ( numToAdd.equals("x") || numToAdd.equals("X") ) {
        keepLooping = false;
    }

    if ( !numToAdd.equals("x") || !numToAdd.equals("X") ) {
        arrayOfNumbers[index] = Integer.parseInt(numToAdd); 
    }

    index++;
}
```

---

But of course, this solves just the filling-of-array issue. Then come the **good practice in programming** concerns, which are thoroughly covered by the rest of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify a little bit with a `for` loop, and `break` out of the loop to exit:

```
for (int index = 0; index < arrayOfNumbers.length; ++index) {
  String numToAdd = keyboard.nextLine();

  if (numToAdd.equals("x") || numToAdd.equals("X")) {
    break;
  }
  arrayOfNumbers[index] = Integer.parseInt(numToAdd); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = 0;
boolean keepLooping = true;

while (index < arrayOfNumbers.length && keepLooping) {
    String numToAdd = keyboard.nextLine();

    if (numToAdd.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) { // Use EqualsIgnoreCase to shorten it
        keepLooping = false;
    } else { // Use an else statement instead of evaluating the inverse
        arrayOfNumbers[index] = Integer.parseInt(numToAdd); 
    }
    index++; // Increment the index to avoid eternal loop and actually fill the array
}
```